# How can I can I reference number 1, 2, or 3 in my echo statement to say "First number is not numeric! Please enter a numeric value for number 1"?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, forms

Do I need to reference my form?

```
<form action="form1.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Please input numeric value in each of three text boxes below:
</legend>
<p><label for="number">number 1: <input type="text" name="number" size="9">
</label></p><br>
<p><label for="number">number 2: <input type="text" name="number2" size="9">
</label></p><br>
<p><label for="number">number 3: <input type="text" name="number3" size="9">
</label></p><br>
</fieldset>
<div id="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

I want be able to have my echo statement state that I am missing a number from one of my textboxes

```
if(empty($_POST['number']) || empty($_POST['number2']) || 
empty($_POST['number3'])){
        echo "You forgot to values for all three textboxes";
    } else { if(!is_numeric($_POST['number']) || 
is_numeric($_POST['number2']) || is_numeric($_POST['number3'])){
        echo "First number is not numeric! Please enter a numeric value for 
number 1";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could (using HTML5) mark your fields as numeric (`type="number"`) fields and as `required`

Comment: Wait, how would I do that? @NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

llike nigel ren say you can use html by added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and change it your input become like this

```
<input type="number" name="number2" size="9">
```

this some snippet for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="form1.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Please input numeric value in each of three text boxes below:
</legend>
<p><label for="number">number 1: <input type="number" name="number" size="9">
</label></p><br>
<p><label for="number">number 2: <input type="number" name="number2" size="9">
</label></p><br>
<p><label for="number">number 3: <input type="number" name="number3" size="9">
</label></p><br>
</fieldset>
<div id="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is_numeric returns false on empty string as well. So you could do something like:

```
if ( ! is_numeric($_POST['number']) ) { echo "First is not numeric"; }
if ( ! is_numeric($_POST['number2']) ) { echo "Second is not numeric"; }
if ( ! is_numeric($_POST['number3']) ) { echo "Third is not numeric"; }
```

This would take place instead of the 2 if blocks you currently have.

This would be good in combination with the HTML5 type="number" as referenced by the above answers as well.

I'm not sure if that answers your question as it seems like you'd like to state which input was not numeric. Your code however does something else. Your first if block checks just to see if ALL are not empty and errors if anyone of them is empty. Your second block of code errors if number is not numeric but will also error if number2 OR number3 is numeric. Which doesn't seem to be the desired outcome.